# Multiple redirects (301)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having an issue with my wordpress site that is hosted by siteground.
I've spent hours trying to solve it but I just don't know enough identify the problem.

If I visit http://cordvision.com it gets redirected to http://www.cordvision.com/ which then gets redirected to https://www.cordvision.com/.

I want it to go directly to https://www.cordvision.com/.

Here is what I believe is the relevant information:

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

```
BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

END WordPress
```

**Wordpress Setting (Settings --> General)**

WordPress Address: https://www.cordvision.com
Site URL: https://www.cordvision.com

**DNS Zone File**
Screenshot of relevant entries:

[image]

I'm using cloudflaire through siteground (dns handled by siteground)

(I found that http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php might offer some useful information
for trouble shooting)

Any chance somebody can identify what causes the unnecessary redirect? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with the nginx server. Is it possible that the redirect is caused by the nginx server?  I don't think there is a way for me to access the nginx config file on a shared hosting account. If it is indeed an issue with the nginx server, would there be a workaround or can it only be solved by siteground itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to automagically redirect from `http://` to `https://www` without the `http://www`step

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #Redirection vers HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

At the very top of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but it made no difference. I still get the exact same "double redirect"...